# Perl regex doesn't grab multiple North American phone numbers in a line

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to grab all NA phone numbers from a CSV file.  The numbers can appear anywhere in each line and each line can also have multiple numbers (separated by commas).  The regex I've come up with does work, at least it grabs the first phone number in the line.  But despite using the "/g" flag it won't grab any of the other phone numbers.  Can anyone suggest what might be wrong with my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use strict;

my $data_file = "test.csv";

open my $FH, "<", $data_file || die "cannot open file\n";

my @lines = <$FH>;


while (@lines) {
if ((shift @lines) =~ /((\(\d{3}\)\s+|\d{3}-?|\d{3}\.?)(\d{3}-?|\d{3}\.?)\d{4})/g) {
    print "$1\n";
} else {
    print "No match\n";
}
}
```

Comment: I just tried the regex on my environment, appeared to work and match all instances (tells me it's something other than the pattern).

Comment: Weird, I'm running this Mac OS 10 Snow Leopard with the default installed version of Perl.  Would it be helpful if I posted the "test.csv" file contents?

Comment: Here's the line that it's tripping up on: "Community Health Partnership: Medical, Dental, & Behavioral",815-539-6124 ,815-539-9015,sbauer@chpofil.org,www.chpofil.org,NULL,NULL,1009 Main Street,Mendota,61342,Yes,Yes,Yes,NULL,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,0:00:00,Susan Bauer,Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` is a scalar, and thus cannot contain multiple matches. You might want to try something like this:

```
my @matches = ((shift @lines) =~ /((?:\(\d{3}\)\s+|\d{3}-?|\d{3}\.?)(?:\d{3}-?|\d{3}\.?)\d{4})/g);
if (@matches) {
    print join("\n", @matches)."\n";
} else {
    print "No match\n";
}
```

Or you could try something like this:

```
my $line = shift @lines;
if ($line =~ /((\(\d{3}\)\s+|\d{3}-?|\d{3}\.?)(\d{3}-?|\d{3}\.?)\d{4})/) {
    while ($line =~ /((\(\d{3}\)\s+|\d{3}-?|\d{3}\.?)(\d{3}-?|\d{3}\.?)\d{4})/g) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
} else {
    print "No match\n";
}
```

Comment: I thought that the contents of $1 would be replaced for each match.  I guess not...